# Request for member 'x' in something not a structure

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Hola que tal he revisado mi código pero no logro ver mi error. Podría alguien iluminarme?
El problema surge al intentar acceder a 'fin'. Al remover estas líneas y des-comentar las líneas que ya estaban, funciona a la perfección. Solo quiero agregar éste apuntador para facilitar la inserción de datos

```
struct lista
{
    int dato;
    struct lista *siguiente; 
    struct lista *fin; //Nuevo apuntador a implementar. 
};

void agregar(struct lista **primero, int r)
{
    struct lista *nvo = (struct lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));

    if(nvo == NULL)
        printf("\nERROR memoria insuficiente...\n");
    else
    {
        nvo->dato = r;
        nvo->siguiente = NULL;

        if(*primero == NULL)
        {
            *primero = nvo;
            *primero->fin = nvo; //Primer intento de acceder a fin
        }
        else
        {
            // Auxiliar para recorrer la lista
            /*
            struct lista *aux1;

            aux1 = *primero;

            while(aux1->siguiente != NULL)
                aux1 = aux1->siguiente;

            aux1->siguiente = nvo;
            */
            *primero->fin->siguiente = nvo; //Segundo intento
            *primero->fin = nvo; //Tercer intento
        }
    }
}
```

El error mostrado es el del titulo de la pregunta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, se mas claro con lo que preguntas. Muestra el mensaje de error y contextualiza un poco para poder entender de mejor manera tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya he agregado un poco mas de informacion para tratar de hacer la pregunta mas clara, aunque ya ha sido resuelta. Espero sirva para futuras consultas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en este caso debes utilizar paréntesis:

```
    if(*primero == NULL)
    {
        *primero = nvo;
        (*primero)->fin = nvo;
    }
    else
    {
        // Auxiliar para recorrer la lista
        /*
        struct lista *aux1;

        aux1 = *primero;

        while(aux1->siguiente != NULL)
            aux1 = aux1->siguiente;

        aux1->siguiente = nvo;
        */

        (*primero)->fin->siguiente = nvo;
        (*primero)->fin = nvo;
    }
```

Esto debido a la precedencia en las operaciones.
Saludos.